# Kotlin collection operations effectiveness

Tags: performance, kotlin, collections, extension-function

I would like to create an extension function for a collection to check if one collection contains any item of defined set.
I think about two implementations:

```
infix fun <T> Iterable<T>.containsAny(values: Iterable<T>): Boolean = any(values::contains)
```

or

```
infix fun <T> Iterable<T>.containsAny(values: Iterable<T>): Boolean = intersect(values).isNotEmpty()
```

The question is which way is more efficient and why? And is there any better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first way with `any` is *O(n*m)* unless the parameter Iterable is a Set, in which case it's *O(n)*.

The second way with `intersect` is *O(n)*.

So the second way is much faster unless the parameter is already a Set or both inputs are so tiny that it's worth iterating repeatedly to avoid copying the receiver Iterable to a MutableSet.

The *O(n)* way could be improved to allow the early exit behavior of `any` by doing this:

```
infix fun <T> Iterable<T>.containsAny(values: Iterable<T>): Boolean =
    any(values.toSet()::contains)
```

and further to avoid an unnecessary set copy:

```
infix fun <T> Iterable<T>.containsAny(values: Iterable<T>): Boolean =
    any((values as? Set<T> ?: values.toSet())::contains)
```

And if the receiver Iterable is usually bigger than the parameter Iterable, you might want to swap which one is the set and which one is being iterated.